# Date and Time Stamp for renaming files without spaces inside a .BAT

Tags: timestamp

I need to do a BAT script to rename a file with date and time stamp, with NO spaces

```
set DD=%date:~-10,2%
set MM=%date:~-7,2%
set YYYY=%date:~-4,4%
set HH=%time:~-11,2%
set MIN=%time:~-8,2%
set SS=%time:~-5,2%

ren File1.txt File1_%YYYY%_%MM%_%DD%__%HH%_%MIN%_%SS%.txt
```

The problem is that when the hour is 1 to 9, the variable HH contents includes a space before the number, for example if the current time is 09:30:15 the HH variable contents will be " 9".

I need to be 09

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!